# Listing arguments for a method node

Tags: c#, opc-ua

I'm trying to list arguments for a method.

When I use the sample client I can see the following information:

[image]

But when I use `_session.Browse()` to get the children of "MethodIO" I can't see the arguments:

```
var browseDescr = new BrowseDescription
{
    NodeId = methodNode.NodeId.ToString(),
    BrowseDirection = BrowseDirection.Forward,
    ReferenceTypeId = ReferenceTypeIds.Aggregates,
    IncludeSubtypes = true,
    NodeClassMask = (uint)(NodeClass.Variable | NodeClass.Object),
    ResultMask = (uint)BrowseResultMask.All
};
var arguments = Browse(browseDescr);
```

Result:

[image]

I've also tried:

1. Browse the children of the `InputArgument` node
2. To use `_session.ReadNode(methodNode.NodeId.ToString());`

So what am I doing wrong? How can I figure out which arguments a method has?

Answer (score 0):

From the screenshot it looks like you're getting the 2 expected nodes back, are you not?

Once you have these nodes, the actual datatype of the input and output arguments to the method are determined by the datatype of the InputArguments and OutputArguments nodes.

Comment: I get no children back for "InputArguments", but according to the description there should be arguments.

Comment: The InputArguments node won't have children. All the information you need is in the attributes of that node itself. The DataType of the Value attribute for InputArguments and OutputArguments is a scalar or array of the Argument structure, which has all the info you need.